# Read Contents from SQL with Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a CMS database with articles in it. And I want to publish this articles via Asp.Net MVC. These articles have their urls.

For example:

```
domain.com/products
domain.com/products/home
domain.com/products/garden
domain.com/products/sport
domain.com/products/sport/baseball
domain.com/products/sport/football ..... etc.
```

Like above, there are 3.000 articles in the database (PathUrl - Content - CreatedDate etc.) These articles stored on ARTICLES table.

I can receive menu items from MENUS table with EF and MVC tools (Controller-Model-View).

Right now, if the main categories are controller, we need to create 30-35 controller manually. How can I do dynamically? Otherwise, do I need routemapping?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to create 30-35 controllers manually. This would usually be handled by routing. I.e., instead of routing requests to CategoryXController, CategoryYController, interpret the category as a parameter on an action method in a higher-level "products" controller.

Comment: This is the condition where routing plays major part, with just few controllers involved. Since your URL follows certain pattern, you can use `{controller}/{action}/{category1}/{category2}/...` as most-specific route on the top, and more general routes follows on bottom.